# How to make a hover function ALSO a click function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I have a tooltip that can be seen below, at the moment it reveals the tooltip only on hover, but I want it to reveal the tooltip when both hovering and clicking (for touch screen devices) could somebody please show me how?

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k62NY/18/)

My javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
  $(this)
    .css('z-index', '10')
    .find('img').addClass("hover")
    .stop()
    .animate({
       marginTop: '-150px',
       marginLeft: '-150px',
       top: '50%',
       left: '50%',
       width: '300px',
       height: '300px',
       padding: '20px'

     }, 200, function() {

        var $this = $(this),
        h = $this.height();
        $caption = $('<div class="caption">' + this.title  + '</div>')
            .css('top', h.toString() + 'px');
            $this.after($caption);

      }); 

   }, function() {

 $('.caption').remove();
 $(this)
.css('z-index', '0')
.find('img').removeClass("hover")
.stop()
.animate({

    marginTop: '0',
    marginLeft: '0',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    width: '200px',
    height: '200px',
    padding: '5px'

 }, 400);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function, let's call it `activate`:

```
function activate(that) {
    //Your code here
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
$("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
    activate($(this));
});

$("ul.thumb li").click(function() {
    activate($(this));
});
```

Note, that `activate` will hold the commands you need to process in those events. Also, in `activate`, try to make sure that you are using `that` instead of `this`.

Comment: Hi, sorry to waste your time but I am a beginner here so that just confused me haha! Is there not a simpler way?

Comment: You are not wasting my time :). You can copy your code from your hover event into the click event, but that is code duplication and it will be troublesome to maintain your code that way. If you ask me, you should create that function and put your code into it, change this with that and use the function in both events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind a handler to multiple events...

First of you need to name the two functions. Then you can use `.on()` as follows:

```
$("ul.thumb li").on('mouseover touchstart', show);
$("ul.thumb li").on('mouseleave touchend', hide);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/62NT7/)

Comment: no, this just made the hover stop working also, thanks though

Comment: @user3760124 check the update. `on()` method is not available prior to jquery 1.71, Updating to latest version of jquery is not an issue i hope..?

Answer (score 0):

First, refactor and rename your hover in and out function:

```
function showTooltip(){
  $(this)
    .css('z-index', '10')
    .find('img').addClass("hover")
    .stop()
  // etc...

}

function hideTooltip(){
  $('.caption').remove();
  $(this)
    .css('z-index', '0')
    .find('img').removeClass("hover")
    .stop()
  // etc...
}
```

Then instead of using the [`hover` shorthand, use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to listen the hovering:

```
$("ul.thumb li")
  .on('mouseenter', showTooltip)
  .on('mouseleave', hideTooltip);
```

If you want to show the tooltip for touch events, just add the `touchstart` event to it: I guess you want to tap to both open and close the tooltip.

```
$("ul.thumb li")
  .on('mouseenter touchstart', showTooltip)
  .on('mouseleave touchstart', hideTooltip);
```

Comment: @MarcoCl thats a great answer but I just tried implementing it and it didn't work, would you be able to show me in context? Thanks!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? In your jsFiddle there's jQuery 1.5 that has not `on` binder, but it still uses the deprecated `live` - if you swap `on` with `live` it works.